# Can't download media files sent to a Whatsapp bot

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bots

I'm having a problem downloading media files that are sent to a Whatsapp bot. I am using NodeJS. I have followed the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media?locale=es_LA#download-media), first doing a GET to https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/<MEDIA_ID> and obtaining the download URL, but when doing the GET to the download URL I get an error 500. I tried through INSOMNIA and Node.
I have attached screenshots of the error messages in Node[Node console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQRZu.png)

First I made a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/<MEDIA_ID>/.
Then, with the result of the previous request I made a GET request to the given URL.
What should happen is that the image is shown (in POSTMAN/INSOMNIA) or I get some download error (in Node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the page access token and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes pleas provide more detail I'm having the same problem